# install mysql client and mysql-server with default charset utf8 to fedora 11

Tags: mysql, fedora, utf-8

I only have utf8 characters to put into my db so like everything in the db is utf8.

I tried 'yum install mysql mysql-server -with-charset=utf8' but it is not right.

if i install using ''yum install mysql mysql-server' i got defaut latin1 charset.

Any suggestion and help are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in /etc/my.cnf

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

if you will use only this charset

for databases already created which use latin1 charset, do the following

```
alter database database_name charset=utf8;
```

for each table:

```
alter table table_name charset=utf8;
```

for each varchar/char type column:

```
alter table table_name alter column column_name charset=utf8;
```

Comment: Restart mysql server after change in /etc/my.cnf

Comment: that goes without saying :) though I should have mentioned it, for a complete answer

thanks